# Iscsi initiator configuration with FusionStor storage

Tags: networking, mount, connection, storage, iscsi

we have FusionStor storage system, and it's connected with Ubuntu OS over the iscsi, we need to do the iscsi configuration, can you pls guide the steps, how we can do the iscsi configuration and map the LUN from storage to OS over the ISCSI connectivity